# D3 add data into array element inside setInterval() to draw grouped bar chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, d3.js

I'm newer for D3.js. I need to design grouped bar chart using array of data set. For this I followed this links. 
[Grouped Bar Chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051) , [D3js take data from an array instead of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639305/d3js-take-data-from-an-array-instead-of-a-file/21668952#)

Here is my code.

```css
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html>
<head> 
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"  charset="utf-8"></script>    

</head>
    
<body>
     
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    
 var interval = setInterval(function() {
                      
                }, 1000);    

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x0)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(""));

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var data = [
    {TestSuite:"TestSuite1",True:2,False:5},
    {TestSuite:"TestSuite2",True:6,False:3},
    {TestSuite:"TestSuite3",True:1,False:7},
    {TestSuite:"TestSuite4",True:5,False:2},
    {TestSuite:"TestSuite5",True:2,False:2},
    {TestSuite:"TestSuite6",True:9,False:4}
];    
 //x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){  
  var ageNames = d3.keys(data[i]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "TestSuite"; });
  
  }
      
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.ages = ageNames.map(function(name) { return {name: name, value: +d[name]}; });
      
  });

  x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.TestSuite; }));
  x1.domain(ageNames).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.ages, function(d) { return d.value; }); })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)  
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Count");

  var state = svg.selectAll(".TestSuite")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.TestSuite) + ",0)"; });

  state.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.name); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(ageNames.slice().reverse())
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });



</script>
    
</body> 
    
</html>
```

But I need to add data to data[] inside setInterval() function as

```js
var data = [];
var i=0;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  // data must be add for each index in each second until i=6(something like this   condition)
  //I tried like this
  if(i<6){
    
     data[i] = {letter:"A",frequency:i};//frequency=i value
  
     /*
     x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
     y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);
     .
     .
     .
     .
     function type(d) {
            d.frequency = +d.frequency;
            return d;
     }
     */
    
   } 
  i++;
},1000);
```

This is not working,Can anyone tell me how to solve this puzzle? how to add data to array and how to create each bar seperatly?
Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the code which generates the bar chart or the rect DOM inside an update block.

Something like the code in fiddle

```js
 var margin = {
     top: 20,
     right: 20,
     bottom: 30,
     left: 40
 },
 width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
     height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

 var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
     .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

 var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

 var y = d3.scale.linear()
     .range([height, 0]);

 var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
     .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6"]);

 var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
     .scale(x0)
     .orient("bottom");

 var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
     .scale(y)
     .orient("left")
     .tickFormat(d3.format(""));
 var w = width + margin.left + margin.right;
 var h = height + margin.top + margin.bottom;
 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
     .attr("width", w)
     .attr("height", h)
     .append("g")
     .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

 var data = [{
     TestSuite: "TestSuite1",
     True: 2,
     False: 5
 }, {
     TestSuite: "TestSuite2",
     True: 6,
     False: 3
 }, {
     TestSuite: "TestSuite3",
     True: 1,
     False: 7
 }, {
     TestSuite: "TestSuite4",
     True: 5,
     False: 2
 }, {
     TestSuite: "TestSuite5",
     True: 2,
     False: 2
 }, {
     TestSuite: "TestSuite6",
     True: 9,
     False: 4
 }];
 var interval = setInterval(function () {
     //add your new fresh data here
     data.push({
         TestSuite: "TestSuite"+Math.round(Math.random()*100) + 1,
         True: Math.round(Math.random()*9) + 1,
         False: Math.round(Math.random()*9) + 1
     });
     update();
 }, 10000);
 //x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));


 var xg = svg.append("g")
     .attr("class", "x axis")
     .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");

 var yg = svg.append("g")
     .attr("class", "y axis");

 yg.append("text")
     .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
     .attr("y", 6)
     .attr("dy", ".71em")
     .style("text-anchor", "end")
     .text("Count");



 update();
//this function will make the bar charts
 function update() {
     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         var ageNames = d3.keys(data[i]).filter(function (key) {
             return key !== "TestSuite";
         });

     }

     data.forEach(function (d) {
         d.ages = ageNames.map(function (name) {
             return {
                 name: name,
                 value: +d[name]
             };
         });

     });

     x0.domain(data.map(function (d) {
         return d.TestSuite;
     }));
     x1.domain(ageNames).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
     y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
         return d3.max(d.ages, function (d) {
             return d.value;
         });
     })]);
     //making the x axis/y axis
     xg.call(xAxis);
     yg.call(yAxis);
     //removing all the rectangles
     svg.selectAll(".TestSuite").remove();
     
     var state = svg.selectAll(".TestSuite")
         .data(data)
         .enter().append("g")
         .attr("class", "TestSuite")
         .attr("transform", function (d) {
         return "translate(" + x0(d.TestSuite) + ",0)";
     });
     
     state.selectAll("rect")
         .data(function (d) {
         return d.ages;
     })
         .enter().append("rect")
         .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
         .attr("x", function (d) {
         return x1(d.name);
     })
         .attr("y", function (d) {
         return y(d.value);
     })
         .attr("height", function (d) {
         return height - y(d.value);
     })
         .style("fill", function (d) {
         return color(d.name);
     });
 }
```

```css
body {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.axis path, .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.bar {
    fill: steelblue;
}
.x.axis path {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Really this is very helpful answer for me...  thanks.

Comment: @cytril , My graph is generated inside a div which has (screen size)/2 width. (width : 50%). When I run the code it generated bars for 15 test suite and then it stop generating bars. What can be the reason for that? (Your answer is very helpful for generate my code,So I think you may know the resson as I have lack of knowledge about D3. If you can, Please give me a clue for solve this problem.)

Comment: Well if you see my example above it just goes on adding bar charts...only issue with this is that the svg size is fixed so the bar charts will start coming one on top off the other...well as the case your reporting the bar charts stop after 15 is really strange....you can do an inspect HTML to see if new bars are generated beyond 15.

Comment: :) you are right,It was a mistake of my code. now it works fine! thank you.