# replacing a tsv data binding with json local data in D3.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am trying to replace the tsv data source showed in the tutorial here:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304#data.tsv

with a local data set defined as json like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: brown;
}

.axis {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js">     </script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10, "%");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


var myData = [{"letter":"A","frequency":0.08167},
        {"letter":"B","frequency":0.01492},
        {"letter":"C","frequency":0.02782},
        {"letter":"D","frequency":0.04253},
        {"letter":"E","frequency":0.12702},
        {"letter":"F","frequency":0.02288},
        {"letter":"G","frequency":0.02015},
        {"letter":"H","frequency":0.06094},
        {"letter":"I","frequency":0.06966},
        {"letter":"J","frequency":0.00153},
        {"letter":"K","frequency":0.00772},
        {"letter":"L","frequency":0.04025},
        {"letter":"M","frequency":0.02406},
        {"letter":"N","frequency":0.06749},
        {"letter":"O","frequency":0.07507},
        {"letter":"P","frequency":0.01929},
        {"letter":"Q","frequency":0.00095},
        {"letter":"R","frequency":0.05987},
        {"letter":"S","frequency":0.06327},
        {"letter":"T","frequency":0.09056},
        {"letter":"U","frequency":0.02758},
        {"letter":"V","frequency":0.00978},
        {"letter":"W","frequency":0.0236},
        {"letter":"X","frequency":0.0015},
        {"letter":"Y","frequency":0.01974},
        {"letter":"Z","frequency":0.00074}];


 function draw(data) {
    function(error, data)


  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Frequency");

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); });
});

function type(d) {
  d.frequency = +d.frequency;
  return d;

}

</script>
```

I was looking at this post:

[Loading D3.js data from a simple JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764698/loading-d3-js-data-from-a-simple-json-string)

but can't figure out how to bind that local data source to draw the chart properly. All help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: nevermind i just found this: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639305/d3js-take-data-from-an-array-instead-of-a-file

I am sorry.

Comment: Flag own question as duplicate?

Comment: @Jesse yes, just did that. Apologies for posting too hastily.