# D3.js replace a tsv file with an array

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have been trying to implement the following [chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955), without using d3.tsv as I am obtaining my data from another source.

Following what was stated in this other similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639305/d3js-take-data-from-an-array-instead-of-a-file), I tried replacing this part of the code:

```
d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;

    var cities = data.columns.slice(1).map(function(id) {
        return {
            id: id,
            values: data.map(function(d) {
                alert(d.date);
                alert(id);
                return {date: d.date, temperature: d[id]};
            })
        };
    });
```

With:

```
var data=[
{date:20111001,temperature:{New York:63.4,San Francisco:62.7,Austin:72.2}},
{date:20111001,temperature:{New York:58.0,San Francisco:59.9,Austin:67.7}}
.
.
.
];
```

But I get the error:

```
SyntaxError: missing : after property id
```

What is the right format for this kind of chart?

Answer (score 3):

Since this is the TSV file's structure:

```
date    New York    San Francisco   Austin
20111001    63.4    62.7    72.2
20111002    58.0    59.9    67.7
20111003    53.3    59.1    69.4
```

It will be parsed to an array of objects by `d3.tsv` function (together with the row function) with this structure:

```
[{
    "date": "2011-09-30T14:00:00.000Z",
    "New York": 63.4,
    "San Francisco": 62.7,
    "Austin": 72.2
}, {
    "date": "2011-10-01T14:00:00.000Z",
    "New York": 58,
    "San Francisco": 59.9,
    "Austin": 67.7
}, {
    "date": "2011-10-02T13:00:00.000Z",
    "New York": 53.3,
    "San Francisco": 59.1,
    "Austin": 69.4
},{
    ...
}]
```

Which has to be the structure of your `data` variable.

Pay attention to this: the dates here are already parsed. If you're gonna use the original values, parse the dates in your `data` array (using a `forEach`, for instance).

**PS**: In your array, `New York` and `San Francisco` are not valid property names. You should use a comma for them:

```
var data = [{
    date: 20111001,
    temperature: {
        "New York": 63.4,
        "San Francisco": 62.7,
        Austin: 72.2
    }
}, {
    date: 20111001,
    temperature: {
        "New York": 58.0,
        "San Francisco": 59.9,
        Austin: 67.7
    }
}];
```