# Accessing data properties for d3 v4 stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, dataset, bar-chart

I have been working on creating a stacked bar chart using d3 v4 but with a JSON file input. This question is a continuation of a past question:[Converting data structure of a JSON array for stacked bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51599670/converting-data-structure-of-a-json-array-for-stacked-bar-chart).

My data array consists of numerous objects (each object is a hospital and has values such as the count of males, females, and categories).

Based from this, how can I access the individual properties of my data array and populate it accordingly? This means that when I hover over a certain bar, the gender type, count, percentage, and categories change.

**EDIT: I changed my post to show a better understanding about my data structure. Also, I do not think the provided link doesn't solve my problem that I have. I did used that method and it didn't work.

**EDIT2: Added more of my JavaScript code

The data structure is in a JSON format (An array of objects) looks like:

```
[{
  "hospitalName": "hospital1",
  "Diseases of the Circulatory System": 1,
  "Diseases of the Digestive System": 1,
  "Diseases of the Nervous System & Sense Organs": 2,
  "Diseases of the Respiratory System": 1,
  "Infectious and Parasitic Diseases": 278,
  "Injury and Poisoning": 9,
  "Mental Disorders": 4,
  "Neoplasms": 4,
  "No Diagnosis Code in Medical Record": 10,
  "Perinatal Period Conditions": 1,              
  "Females": 223,  
  "Males": 88,    
  "Unknown": 0,
  "count": 311
 },
 { 
   "hospitalName": "hospital2",
   "No Diagnosis Code in Medical Record": 1,
   "Females": 0,
   "Males": 1,
   "Unknown": 0,
   "count": 1
 },
 {
   "hospitalName": "hospital3",
   "Neoplasms": 5,
   "Females": 0,
   "Males": 2,
   "Unknown": 3,
   "count": 5
 }]
```

This is my current stacked bar chart.

[image]

The output of the tooltip would look something like this:

[image]

*My JavaScript code:

```
   var svg = d3.select("svg"),
   margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 120, left: 40 },
   width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
   height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
   g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

   var x = d3.scaleBand()
   .rangeRound([0, width])
   .paddingInner(0.15)
   .align(0.1);

   var y = d3.scaleLinear()
   .rangeRound([height, 0]);


   var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
   .range(["#a95e65", "#5eaaa2", "#6b486b"]);


   d3.json("hospitals2.json", function(error, data) {

    if (error) throw error;

    var newData = {};

    data.forEach(element => {

    var name = element.hospitalName;
    var hospital = newData[name];

    if (!hospital) {
        hospital = { hospitalName: name, Females: 0, Males: 0, Unknown: 0, count: 0 };
        newData[name] = hospital;
    }

    hospital[element.category] = +element.count;
    hospital.Females += +element.Females;
    hospital.Males += +element.Males;
    hospital.Unknown += +element.Unknown;
    hospital.count += +element.count;

    });

    data = [];

    for (const key in newData) {
    if (newData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        data.push(newData[key]);
     }
   }

console.log(data);

var columns = d3.keys(data[0]);

var keys = columns.slice(1, 4);

console.log(keys);

data.sort(function(a, b) { return b.total - a.total; });
x.domain(data.map(function(d, i) { return i; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.count; })]).nice();
z.domain(keys);

g.append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(d3.stack().keys(keys)(data))
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return d; })
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x(i); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .on("mousemove", function(d) {
        var xPosition = d3.mouse(this)[0] - 60;
        var yPosition = d3.mouse(this)[1] - 60;

        tooltip.attr("transform", "translate(" + xPosition + "," + yPosition + ")");

        tooltip.select(".count").html("Count: " + (d[1] - d[0]) + "<br>")
        tooltip.select(".percent").html("(" + (Math.round((d[1] - d[0]) / d.data.count * 100)) + "%" + ")")



    })
    .on("mouseover", function() {
        tooltip.style("display", "inline");

    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
        tooltip.style("display", "none");

    });

g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(function(d, i) { return data[i].MTFID }))
    .selectAll("text")
    .attr("x", -11)
    .attr("y", 7)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(290)")
    .style("text-anchor", "end");

g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, "s"))
    //.call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickFormat(d => Math.round(d * 100 / d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.count })) + "%"))
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", 2)
    .attr("y", y(y.ticks().pop()) + 0.5)
    .attr("dy", "0.32em")
    .attr("fill", "#000")
    .attr("font-family", "Montserrat, sans-serif")
    .attr("font-size", "13px")
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .text("Population");

var legend = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(keys.slice().reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

legend.append("rect")
    .attr("x", width - 19)
    .attr("width", 19)
    .attr("height", 19)
    .attr("fill", z);

legend.append("text")
    .attr("x", width - 24)
    .attr("y", 9.5)
    .attr("dy", "0.32em")
    .text(function(d) { return d; });


var tooltip = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("display", "none");


tooltip.append("rect")
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 105)
    .attr("fill", "#DCDCDC")

tooltip.append("text")
    .attr("class", "count")
    .attr("x", 50)
    .attr("dy", "1.2em")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")


tooltip.append("text")
    .attr("class", "percent")
    .attr("x", 50)
    .attr("dy", "2em")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")

tooltip.append("text")
    .attr("class", "category")


  });
```

Comment: Okay, I edited my question to provide a better understanding.